# Get Files/Folders with corrupted NTFS permissions

Tags: powershell, ntfs

Occasionally from time to time, a file or folder has corrupted permissions. You cannot delete, rename, take ownership, etc of it.

I'm looking for a script that loop on the folders structure and find all these files/folders.
Unfortunately google didn't help me :(

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Post that and also clarify if you want to just loop and list the files or it's permissions ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried **ICACLS.EXE** and its **/verify** switch?  This would be my starting point.  Depending on how foo-bar'd the DACLS are, you may be able to use **ICACLS.EXE** or **SETOWN.EXE** to fix ownership.